# Android Font Face in onCreateView of a fragment.

Tags: android, fonts

How do you get a .ttf file from assets in the onCreateView method of a fragment?

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Thin.ttf");
```

I'm getting an error at the getAssets() method. "The method getAssets() is undefined for the type"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getAssets()` is a method on `Activity`. Your `onCreateView()`, presumably, is in a `Fragment`. Call `getActivity().getAssets()` in a `Fragment` to get at an `AssetManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the fragment...

You can simply do `getActivity().getAssets()` but you should do it in onCreate vs onCreateView since onCreateView has a potential of getting called more times than onCreate. See the [fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).